# How do I find my Wordpress spam URL injection?

Tags: php, wordpress, code-injection, spam

Let me start by saying I am not a highly experienced PHP individual but I am not a novice either.

It has been brought to my attention that my website has had a URL injected on every page with a spam link to an adult site. It is invisible but if you press control+F on any page and search for it, it will show up. Also, if you check the page source you can see where it has been added.

I started by doing the logical things:

1 - I downloaded the entire site locally and using Notepad++ searched through all the files for the url syntax. It returned no hits.

2 - Then I downloaded the entire database (SQL format) and searched it for the syntax as well. However, it too returned no hits.

I would have thought that syntax would show up in one of those two areas but it does not. What do I do now? Where else could this url be hiding and injected from?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the link to your wordpress website? To see how SQL gets injected

Comment: Here is the site: http://richardrosenman.com/

Comment: Most likely it's been obfuscated. Look for `base64_decode` in your files.

Comment: I can confirm I get 22 files that contain `base64_decode` in them, including the SQL file that contains 3 hits. How would I go about finding out which one of those files is the culprit, if this is indeed the injection?

Comment: check footer.php, functions.php in your wp-content/themes folder, general-template.php in wp-includes folder 
Next time integrate git with Wordpress to check for file changes
use Wordfence, jetpack plugins

Comment: In view-source, I can see that it is being included under footer tag so it must be in one of those files I shared or may be due to plugins folders
But not related to DB, in my opinion

Comment: Let me have a closer look for this Santhosh. Turns out I was searching the wrong site so it might be in the files you mentioned. I'll let you know the results in a little while. Thank you for this.

Comment: I did some scanning in your website and it looks like from wordpress to plugins like WooCommerce, Yoast SEO are all older version which has many vulnerabilities. Just checking further more(only in defensive way and not offensive)

Comment: Santhosh, you were right. Now that I've done a 'find in files' search for the syntax on the correct website, it found 1 hit in footer.php. Here is the entry: `<!-- /#inner-wrapper -->
<style>.uescort {clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px,0px 0px, 0px 0px);position: absolute !important;white-space: nowrap;height: 1px;width: 1px;overflow: hidden;}</style>
<h1 class="uescort"><a href="https://www.uescort.com/" target="_blank">Adultwork</a></h1>
</div><!-- /#wrapper -->` I can simply remove this and that's that?

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. A BIG thank you for your help! I don't see the 'mark-as-answered' button though.

Comment: added it as answer.
Please select it and close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check **footer.php, functions.php** in your **wp-content/themes** folder, **general-template.php** in **wp-includes** folder.

Next time integrate git with Wordpress to check for file changes.
Recommended to install Wordfence, jetpack plugins for better security.